# Meaning of 'instantiation' with respect to templates

Tags: c++, templates

> Note that code is instantiated only for member functions that are called. For class templates, member functions are instantiated only when they are used.

The above quote is from the book: *C++ Templates by Addison Wesley*.

I want to understand the meaning of the jargon "*code is instantiated*". Does it mean that only a particular memory is reserved, or only that code is compiled or something else?

Comment: I think it refers to the process of turning the template into real C++  and then into machine code. My question is, though, when it says "only when they are used" is that at runtime!?!? That can't be, but if not, how is it any different than the 1st sentence? I mean, what's the difference between "when called" and "when used"?

Comment: @Robert: It means unless there exists some code which uses that particular function. Templates are compile time constructs so It can't mean runtime.

Comment: @Robert there are slight differences between *use* and *called*, but the author probably just meant to insist on the same concept: unless it is used, it won't be instantiated. For an example of *use* that does not imply *call*, you can take the address of a function and never use that pointer.

Comment: But the quoted sentences read as if they are making a distinction: template<primitive> --> when "called"; template<class> --> when "used"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a quite interesting question that should be done in the wider context of how templates are processed by the compiler. Basically templates are code patterns from which the compiler generates classes of functions. A template can be used to generate anything from no code at all (if never used) to an indefinite number of instantiations.

Templates are not directly *compiled* into any short of entity that is later used with different arguments (that is true in C# generics, but not C++), but rather the code is parsed by the compiler and maintained in memory in case it is later use while processing the current translation unit. That is, the compiler processes the *template* (*template* in italics is used in the english form of a pattern from which to create things, not the precise C++ meaning) from which it will create the code (classes or functions) when needed. *Instantiation* is the process by which the compiler determines that a particular template is *used* with a particular set of arguments and performs *argument substitution* on the *template* to generate the class or function to compile and the final compilation into binary code of the template.

There are two types of template instantiations, *implicit* and *explicit*, and the quote you refer to is about *implicit template instantiations*. I will start with *explicit template instantiation* just because it is simpler though. When you *explicitly instantiate a template* (google for the syntax) you tell the compiler that you want code generated from that *template* applied to the particular arguments that you provide. In the case of a *class-template*, that forces the instantiation of all of the member functions, which basically means that the compiler will substitute types and compile the result of that into binary objects.

*Implicit instantiation*, on the other hand, is performed on demand. When you use a class template, the bits and pieces that are actually *used* get generated from the *template* and compiled into the translation unit. If you create a variable definition `std::vector<int> v;`, the compiler will apply the type `int` (and the defaulted type `std::allocator<int>`) to the `template std::vector` and create a type `std::vector<int>`, but in doing so, it does not compile all of the member functions, but only those needed, which in this case it would be the *default constructor* `std::vector<int>::vector()`, and the destructor `std::vector<int>::~vector()`. The rest of the methods do not get compiled and there will be no code in the binary for them.

There are a few reasons for not *instantiating* all of the member functions, and the reasons range in complexity from simple to deep in language details. For some of the simpler ones, you can consider performance of compilation (not having to generate/compile all member functions just because one of them is used will reduce compile time by quite a bit). Slightly more complex is the fact that different member functions in the template might impose different requirements on the instantiating type. For example, `operator[]` on a `map` requires that the type of the value is *default-constructible*, as the operator will create a new element if it did not exist in the map already, on the other hand, if you always use `find` and `insert`, you can use `std::map` with types that are not default constructible. By not forcing the compilation of all member functions, the language allows you to use the template with arguments that would not meet all of the requirements of all of the methods, as long as it does meet the requirements of those methods that are actually *used*.

I have employed the term *used* quite a bit in the descriptions above, but I have not yet defined it. For a precise definition you would have to go to the standard, but you can consider as a good approximation that a member function is *used* if it is *called* directly or indirectly from your code (i.e. you call it, or some other member function that you instantiate calls it) or if your obtain the address of the member function.

Comment: That was a helpful and nearly complete answer. Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask for a further clarification of "used"? Specifically, sometimes I am unclear about "when it is used" -- do you mean, when it is used in the codebase and encountered by the compiler? Or when it is encountered during execution?

Comment: @Robert: Compile time, when some parts of your code *use* the function (call it, or obtain the address...). Templates are resolved completely at compile time, and that is where it matters. Of course, everything that is used at runtime has been previously compiled, but that opposite is not true. Consider: `if ( (x % 2) && !(x & 0x01) ) { doSomething(); }`. The `doSomething()` function is *used* in the program, even if the condition in the `if` cannot be met and thus it will never actually *execute* the function.

Answer (score 1):

The important point is that a template method in a class is only going to be compiled if some code is calling it. This has the implication that a template method that could NOT be compiled is not a problem if no one is referring to it.

Like a function that is going to generate a runtime error is not a problem unless it's called, a template function that is going to generate a compiler error when instantiated is not a problem unless someone instantiates it. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    const T& x;

    Foo(const T& x) : x(x) {}

    template<typename S>
    operator S () const
    {
        S s;
        s = x + 1;
        return s;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string s = "bar";
    int i = 42;
    Foo<std::string> fs(s);
    Foo<int> fi(i);

    printf("Here we go... -> %f\n", double(fi));
    // printf("This won't compile -> %f\n", double(fs));
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles, even if when instantiating `Foo<std::string>` it would be illegal to instantiate an implicit conversion to double (because `x+1` is illegal with `std::string`).

If you remove the comment instead this is required and the program will not compile.

Comment: No. Only "instantiation" errors. A template must be valid C++ code as far is possible considering that the template parameters are not yet known. If you make a syntax error in a template the program will not compile even if no one is using the template. If the error is present or not depending on the parameters instead then the template itself will be parsed correctly and an error will be generated only if when substituting the specific template parameters the code would become invalid in C++ (like in the example if you remove the comment).

Comment: So, in a nutshell you mean, that e.g. the pointer variables can't be subtracted from each other, and if I try to do the same, I won't get an error, if I don't call the function containing it?

Comment: No. You must not COMPILE a function that would need that template. If in a template you compute `a - b` where `a` and `b` are instances of two types passed as parameters and you instantiate the template using `<int*, int*>` it will be ok (because it's legal to subtract two int pointers), if your program uses `<double*, int*>` instead you will get a compile error **even if that happens in a function that's never called**. With templates the compilation is basically split in two steps... first parsing (always) and then actual code generation (when you instantiate the template).

Comment: @6502: wrt two-phases, unless you're using a non-compliant compiler such as MSVC...

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is referring to the fact that template code that is not used is never even looked at by the compiler.  A result of this is that you can have, for example, syntax errors in a class template that will not cause compilation errors if the class is never used in your code.

Comment: This is not correct. A template function must be correctly parsed otherwise you will get a compile error. What is not a problem is if an error would happen **when the template is instantiated** with template parameters.

Comment: yeah I guess I should have been more specific... obviously it has to parse - I just meant that its possible to have obviously erroneous code (e.g., `vector<int> x; x.push_back("asdf");`) that doesn't fail until you actually instantiate the template class in your code.  In fact, I was trying to say exactly what you said in your comment above.

Comment: @Cechner: That example isn't actually a syntax error. Also, it looks like code that would still cause an error: there's no dependency on a template parameter.

Comment: @MSalters: well I can tell you it doesn't (VS2010)... (perhaps you're misunderstanding - the code quoted should be somewhere in the definition of a class template)

Comment: @Cechner: that compiler is famously broken in this respect. It fails to detect many template errors due to a broken instantiation model.

Comment: @MSalters: actually, just tried it with GCC and it works there: http://ideone.com/9RbGl . Perhaps you didn't understand my point...

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. "code is instantiated" means the code is put into the memory (code segment). This happens only if the particular method / variable is **referred** in the code.

(The term *Referred* doesn't mean the function is called at runtime. It means the method is present somewhere in your code. So if the method is *referred* then it will be compiled and the code for that will be emitted.)

For example,

```
template<typename T>
T add(T a, T b) { return a + b; }
```

Now if you have referring in your code for type `double` as,

```
double d = add(2.3, 4.6);
```

then compiler will emit the code only for `add<double>()`. There is no point for emitting the code for `add<int>()` or `add<A>()`.

Comment: does that mean it won't be compiled even until called?

Comment: so another jargon is "emitting"? What does that mean?

Comment: You may want to rephrase - yes here appear to refer to run time, while you meant compile time

Comment: @Anisha, if it's referred (not called at runtime) then the code will be emitted. Ofcourse it will be compiled to emit the code. If the reference of the function is present anywhere in the code; that particular `template` code will be emitted/compiled; even if it is never going to be *called*.

Comment: *code is put into the memory (code segment)*... I understand what you mean, but that is not strictly correct if you refer to the program's memory (as compared to the compiler's memory): the function is compiled and code is generated, but it might later be dropped by the linker if it can prove that it is not used (if for example, the function where the implicit instantiation is performed is not *used* in the program)

Answer (score 0):

The process of replacing template parameters by concrete types is called **Instantiation**. It results in the Instance of the template. i.e. The compiler generates the code for template function/class with the requested *type*.

The compiler generates the code for member functions of a template class only if the member function is used(called) or the code is not generated by the compiler at all. This is adherence with the basic principle for C++, **You pay for what you use**.

The statement from the book explains that.

Comment: Yeah, and what "exactly" does that "generated" word mean in this context?

Comment: @Anisha: *Generated* means the compiler creates the code for that member function receving particular data type parameters & writes this code somewhere in the code segment so that, it becomes a part of the object file that gets created after compilation.

Comment: Why on earth are you not using the "straight" words? What is "creating the code"? Do you mean "compiling the code"?

Comment: @Anisha: Okay, simple words. Consider a function template. When you use it with different data types. It is the compiler which actually *creates* the object code for versions of the function which take different data types. *creates* here means compiler *actually writes* the object code for those functions, as if you had an c++ code written for those function versions in your cpp file, The difference is there is only one generic version of function and compiler is intelligent enough to write object code for requested concrete types on the fly by itself, without you explicitly writing the code.